# Extending Python with C Error: Segmentation Fault: 11 in Python [MacOS X]

Tags: python, distutils

I have written an extension module in C with the name **extmodule.c** and the code for it is as follows:

```
#include <Python.h>

//Define a new exception object for our module
static PyObject *extError;

static PyObject* ext_cpu(PyObject* self, PyObject *args)
{
  int pid;
  int sts=0;

  //We expect at least 1 argument to this function
  if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &pid))
  {
    return NULL;
  }


  printf("Hello, from C World! Pid: %i", pid);
  sts=pid;

  return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef ext_methods[] = {
  //PythonName, C-FunctionName, argument_presentation, description
  {"cpu", ext_cpu, METH_VARARGS, "Print cpu consumption of a particular process with pid"}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_ext(void)
{
    PyObject *m;

    m = PyModule_Create(&ext_methods);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    extError = PyErr_NewException("spam.error", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(extError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "error", extError);
    return m;
}
```

After that I have created a **setup.py** to build and install the extension file in my python program and the code for the setup.py is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('ext',
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'],
    libraries = ['pthread'],
    sources = ['extmodule.c'])

setup (name = 'ext',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'This is a C extension for Python program',
    author = 'Somdip Dey',
    url = '',
    ext_modules = [module1])
```

Now on the command prompt I have built the setup.py using the following commands:

```
>> python setup.py build
```

> running build 
>   running build_ext
>
> building 'ext' extension gcc
>   -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/somdipdey/ anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/include
>   -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/somdipdey/anaco nda3/include/python3.6m -c extmodule.c -o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/extmodule.o extmodule.c:34:25:
>   warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'PyMethodDef (*)[1]' to
>   parameter of type
>         'struct PyModuleDef *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>       m = PyModule_Create(&ext_methods);
>   /Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/modsupport.h:158:26:
>   note: expanded from macro 'PyModule_Create'
>           PyModule_Create2(module, PYTHON_API_VERSION)
>                            ^~~~~~ /Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/modsupport.h:150:60:
>   note: passing argument to parameter here PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *)
>   PyModule_Create2(struct PyModuleDef*,
>                                                              ^ 1 warning generated. gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup
>   -L/Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/lib -arch x86
>   _64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/extmodule.o -L/Users/somdipdey/anaconda3/lib -lpthread -o build/lib.macosx-
>   10.7-x86_64-3.6/ext.cpython-36m-darwin.so

```
>> python setup.py install
```

The install command worked properly but the build one gave 1 warning. Now when I am trying to **import ext** in my python program and use the function **ext.cpu(integer_value)**, the program is giving me the following error:

> Segmentation Fault: 11

Any idea what might be causing the issue and how to get rid of it?

Comment: `ncompatible pointer types passing 'PyMethodDef (*)[1]' to
> parameter of type
>       'struct PyModuleDef *'` that's a serious warning. Means that the underlying code will read a pymodule but you pass a pymethod...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am following a tutorial and wrote the code, so I have no prior knowledge in how to achieve that. Do you please happen to know how I can work around it? The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6cvSkbWG3s

Comment: You need to read [the actual docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html). Also, while it's worth struggling through this once just to see what all the pieces are, unless you really like low-level C programming, you should seriously consider writing your extensions in Cython, or at least in a slightly higher-level language with a library that can automate all the annoying stuff for you, like C++ with PyCxx, Boost, or CPyExt, D with Pyd, Rust with rust-python, etc. No more screwing around with hard-to-debug tables, refcount headaches, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, in some cases it's easier to write a C library with a plain old C API, built as a plain old dylib/so/dll, and then use either `cffi` or `ctypes` to wrap it from Python, or a library like SWIG to build a wrapper automatically.

Comment: @abarnert I am completely new to these stuff. Was a C# programmer but now came to C domain. On top the reason for doing low-level C programming is to access each performance counters of the hardware and hence building c extension programs to be able to use it from python program (I am more comfortable using python than C for sure). Anyhow, do you think I can use Cython for such low level C programming?

Comment: @TheCoder Well, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may need a combination of C and Cython for that. Cython code can call C functions, but there are some things that aren't as easy (or even possible, for things like inline asm) to write directly in Cython. And if it really is just trivial low-level calls, I think a C dylib plus cffi might be even easier here. Or C++/D/Rust/etc. (It would be really nice if there were a good tutorial showing all the different option and their strengths and weaknesses, but I'm not aware of one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you exactly what's wrong: you're passing a `PyMethodDef (*)[1]` to `PyModule_Create`, when it expected a `PyModuleDef *`. Those are completely unrelated types. The segfault you're getting is like the C version of a `TypeError`.

[You need to create a module definition table](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function), and pass *that* to [`PyModule_Create`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_Create).

---

If you fix that, you may or may not have another segfault, or garbage data, or a mysterious segfault on exit, because your method table is missing the empty row at the end. C arrays don't know their size the way Python lists do, so code that uses them either needs to pass around the size in a separate variable, or use some "sentinel" value in the last slot. `PyMethodDef` uses the latter solution.

---

So:

```
static PyMethodDef ext_methods[] = {
  //PythonName, C-FunctionName, argument_presentation, description
  {"cpu", ext_cpu, METH_VARARGS, "Print cpu consumption of a particular process with pid"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef ext_module = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "ext",
  "Extension module that does stuff",
  -1,
  ext_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_ext(void)
{
    PyObject *m;

    m = PyModule_Create(&ext_module);
    // the rest is the same as before
```

With those changes, your module builds without warnings, and:

```
>>> import ext
>>> ext.cpu(23)
Hello, from C World! Pid: 23
>>> ^D
```

… everything works fine.

(Well, there might be a memory leak in there, but that's a separate issue…)